# Android Google Maps: How to calculate the distance between the middle of the screen/map and the top of the screen

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to calculate the distance from the middle of the screen/map(shown) to the top of the screen. I have some kind of algorithm that does this but I am not sure that it works properly. I am getting numbers like 6367 and above. Here is my algorithm:

```
    double Radius = 6367.45;
    LatLngBounds bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

    LatLng center = bounds.getCenter();
    LatLng north = bounds.northeast;

    // Convert lat or lng from decimal degrees into radians (divide by 57.2958)
    double centerLat = center.latitude / 57.2958;
    double centerLong = center.longitude / 57.2958;
    double northLat = north.latitude / 57.2958;
    double northLong = north.longitude / 57.2958;

    // distance = circle radius from center to top of the screen
    // this I ma not sure if it returns true numbers like amm real distance
    // and I call it in the setOnCameraChangeListener on every zoom right?
    // yes
    boundRadius = Radius*(Math.acos(Math.sin(centerLat) * Math.sin(northLat) + Math.cos(centerLat)*Math.cos(northLat)*Math.cos(northLong - centerLong)));
```

Am I calculating it correctly? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't understand, do you want to get the distance in map terms or in screen terms? 
Do you need map distance or "actionbar+systembar" distance?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `distanceBetween()` [(documentation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html). I believe it takes the curvature of the Earth into consideration.